# specify one of two attributes as required in custom JSP tag

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

Attributes in Custom JSP tag can be set as required by using the following snippet:

```
<attribute>
    <name>imageId</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
```

Is there any way to specify one of two attributes as required?

Comment: one required and the other not?, one with required true, the other with required false.

Comment: one of the two is required. Example: I have 2 attributes - Id, Name. My requirement is that either Id or Name to be provided for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can make an attribute optional or mandatory.There is not a way to put a condition which can check if one of them is there.

From Documentation

```
<required>true | false</required>

  (Optional) Defines whether this attribute has optional use in the JSP page.

  If not defined here, the default is false — that is, the attribute is optional by
  default.

  If true is specified, and the attribute is not used in a JSP page, a
  translation-time error occurs.
```

### See Also

- [Default value on JSP custom-tag attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136415/default-value-on-jsp-custom-tag-attribute)